# How do I write an iterative function that computes the sum of the first n odd numbers it returns 1 + 3 + .... + (2n - 1), using a for loop?

Tags: python

Assuming that `n` is a positive integer

this is my code:

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
    x =1
    for x in range(n):
        if x%2==1:
            continue
        return x + 2
```

but when I run it on Python it gives me the answer `2`. Could you help me by telling me what's wrong and what I should do to solve this?

Comment: You are returning from inside the loop, so the loop never finishes. Move the `return` out.

Comment: You have a `return`within the loop, so you break out at the first result

Comment: If you do not need the loop for Python learning, the result is N*N.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to find the sum of first 'n' odd numbers, I suggest you to use range function with step=2. I'll elaborate:

```
def sum_n(n):
    addition=0
    for x in range(1,2*n,2):
        addition+=x
    return addition
s=sum_n(5)
print(s)
```

This gives output as: `25`

Here, in range function, 1st attribute provides starting point, 2nd attribute provides the end point, and 3rd attribute gives the Difference between each number in the sequence.
I hope this helps.

Comment: As you asked in the problem, this is done using for loop. Otherwise, answer provided by Joe Iddon will do the same.

Comment: can you explain why you wrote addition=0? what does that stand for? and why is the stop=2*n? also could you explain what addition+=x means? thank u for ur help!

Comment: It is inside the function, So when you all the function, It will reset the value of addition to 0. If you don't add this,whenever you call this function next time, it will start with it's previous value(in this case, 25) stored in it, and will provide a wrong answer.

Comment: Stop is 2*n because: for ex. you want to find sum of first 3 no., then stop point will be 2*n=6, so it will iterate till 6 with difference=2, giving the sum of 1,3 and 5

Comment: addition+=x is just a short-form of addition=addition+x. x is just a variable which represents the integer which is to be iterated at that time.

Comment: If you don't initialize `addition` before the loop you will get an error when you try to add `x` to it. The function will not remember the previous values of it's local variables next time it's called.

Comment: If it solved your problem, kindly mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

- The first is that you have a return statement inside the for loop.
- Secondly, you just visit the first n integers and check which of them are odd. You won't visit all the first n odd integers.

A list comprehension solution solution is as follows.

```html
def sum_odd_n(n):
    # sum up the first n odd numbers
    return sum([2*i + 1 for i in range(n)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this program it will work:

```
a=int(input("how many first odd number sum you want"))

x=1

i=0

def OddSum():

      global i
      global x
      while i<=a:
            x+=2
            i+=1
      print(x)
OddSum()
```

Comment: In general having global variables is not considered good code. I recomend you add a as an argument and define x and inside of `OddSum`

Comment: A key part of object oriented code(python f.e) is that information shouldn't be shared, or atleast as little as possible. It's just the norm.